# CRUD Mysql , preciso de um botão que preencha inputs

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, banco-de-dados

Bom dia, eu tenho uma duvida sobre como fazer os inputs acima recebam dados do meu banco de dados, por exemplo: vamos supor que eu vá alterar algo, mais eu só quero alterar um valor o cep(só um exemplo) mas para alteralo eu preciso saber todos os outros valores para não os deixar em branco, ou seja eu quero que quando eu clicar em update a tabela seja preenchida com os valores antigos fazendo com que eu só tenha que editar :D[image: è assim que está meu site agora e aqueles são os botões que vão me levar a tabela de delete e update]

```html
  
   <form action="editar.php" method="POST">
   <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Cpf Novo</th>
     <th>Nome Novo</th>
     <th>Cep Novo</th>
     <th>Rua Novo</th>
     <th>Bairro Novo</th>
     <th>Cidade Novo</th>
     <th>Estado Novo</th>
     <th>Ibge Novo</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    
   <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="text" onclick="" class="form-control input-sm" id="cpf" name="cpf" required><br></td>
   
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="nom" required><br></td>

    
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="cep" name="end" required><br></td>
    
          <td><input name="rua" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="rua" required /><br></td>
          
          <td><input name="bairro" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="bairro" required/><br></td>
          
          <td><input name="cidade" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="cidade" required/><br></td>
          
          <td><input name="uf" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="uf" required/><br></td>
         
          <td><input name="ibge" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="ibge" required/><br></td>
         </tr>
         </tbody>
         </table>
    <br><input type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Voltar"
onclick="window.location='/Banco_de_dados/index.php';" />
   </form>


</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "meubd";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT nome, cpf, cep, rua, bairro, cidade, estado, ibge FROM pessoas";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

?>
<div>
<table class="table table-striped" id="myTable">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>CPF</th>
   <th>Nome</th>
   <th>Cidade</th>
   <th>estado</th>
   <th></th>
   <th></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <?php 
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  
  
  ?>
  <tr>
   <td><?=$row['cpf']?></td>
   <td><?=$row['nome']?></td>
   <td><?=$row['cidade']?></td>
   <td><?=$row['estado']?></td>
   <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete"
onclick="window.location='/Banco_de_dados/delete.html';" /></td>
   <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update"
onclick="window.location='/Banco_de_dados/editar.html';" /></td> 
  </tr>
  <?php 
  }
  ?>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Pra isso você vai precisar de ajax

Comment: Qual é página dos inputs, para editar? Pode pode simplesmente mandar parametros via get

Comment: Coloquei logo acima os inputs que devem receber os valores

Comment: tenta editar a sua pergunta e só deixar o código que realmente precisa para o que precisa, com todo o código fica até um pouco complicado

Comment: Pronto alterado, só as partes importantes agora.

Comment: Podes organizar melhor a pergunta, adicionando do que se trata o código adicionado logo acima dele?

Comment: Pronto não sei se da de entender melhor, mas oque eu quero é a ajuda de vocês para passar os valores do meu banco para os inputs quando eu clicar em update :D

Comment: Sugiro que você conheça o plugin para jQuery para tratar de grids: [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). É gratuito, bem documentado, e irá te ajudar a resolver essa situação. Eu vejo outros problemas no seu código, mas se usar esse plugin, irá, naturalmente, corrigi-los.

Comment: Sim eu tenho um conhecimento bom sobre o jquery, porém sempre me bagunço e não sei qual comando usar, você poderia me ajudar? ou pelo menos me dizer oque fazer, se tiver algum site que ensine oque é preciso fazer também pode me passar, obrigado a todos foram de grande ajuda até o momento :D!!!

Comment: E sobre os erro comentados pode me apontar eles? é que estou com um pouco de pressa